# what is correct event for input value change on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

what is correct event handler that works similar as in 'onblur' or 'onkeyup' event on desktop?

I have

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="function" data-bind="value:referrerFirstName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'">
```

and this seems to be not working stable in all mobile browser. So I'm looking for a proper way to detect when user moves to the next input field or done editing.

whenever user inputs character, I would like to call this function. But on Firefox mobile version, it's not triggered all the time.

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to be not working stable"? Can you show us some code, which doesn't work?

Comment: You can check  the list of [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) and choose what you need.